# Update/Add one environment variable for Azure Container App

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-container-apps

I would like to update one environment variable value for Azure Container App using Terraform. To accomplish this I am using "azapi_update_resource" but when I do so it removes all and add the one trying to add.

How can I update single environment value with the help of "azapi_update_resource" or is it not possible?

Below is the sample code I have tried and it's not working.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source = "Azure/azapi"
    }
  }
}

provider "azapi" {
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "resource_group"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "acctest-01"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "example" {
  name                       = "Example-Environment"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
}
resource "azurerm_container_app" "example" {
  name                         = "example-app"
  container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.example.id
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  revision_mode                = "Single"

  template {
    container {
      name   = "examplecontainerapp"
      image  = "mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/containerapps-helloworld:latest"
      cpu    = 0.25
      memory = "0.5Gi"

        env {
            name = "keyname"
            value = "keyvalue"
        }
    }
  }
}

resource "azapi_update_resource" "example" {
  type        = "Microsoft.App/containerApps@2022-10-01"
  resource_id = azurerm_container_app.example.id
  
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      template = {
        containers = [
          {
            env = [
              {
                name = "testname"
                value = "testvalue"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do it this way, instead of just adding it to the environment variables declared in the `azurerm_container_app` resource? The way you are doing it is really not the way Terraform was designed to be used.

Comment: @MarkB The example I gave you not the best one but we have a need where we need to update the environment variable of already created azure container app from different module. Please feel free if I am going in wrong direction

Comment: Is the other module still included in the same terraform environment? Or is it completely separate?

Comment: @MarkB In the same terraform environment

Comment: You really left too much out of your question for anybody to help you with this problem. What you need to do is have the module output the value needed in the environment variable, and just use that output as one of the environment variables in the `azurerm_container_app_environment` resource. The way you are currently doing it is extremely fragile and not recommended by Terraform.

Comment: @MarkB azurerm_container_app_environment does not have any environment variable settings. Environment variable settings is in "azurerm_container_app". Not sure what additional information you need but the ask is simple. We would like to add a new environment variable after the container app is created. See the answer for one of the option.

Comment: I meant the `azurerm_container_app` resource, not `azurerm_container_app_environment`

Comment: The additional information is the details of the module you are using. But was my comment not enough to point you in the right direction? Do you not understand what I mean by using the output from the module to set the environment variable?

Comment: First of all you mentioned to use "azurerm_container_app" so that's clear now. Second I know what you mean by passing output. The problem is when we use "azapi_update_resource" it doesn't add new environment value it removes all and add only one. That is the whole problem that I am asking for help.

Comment: @MarkB If you know how to do this please update my example with the answer

Comment: you could prob get a reference of the existing container app, get the existing env var and merge that ?

Comment: @Thomas Yeah that could be a good solution, bit of overhead but seems like a good solution

Answer (score 0):

In your module, add an [output](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/outputs):

```
output "my_module_value" {
  value = "testvalue"  # Whatever value reference you need here
}
```

Then in your top level Terraform, reference that output:

```
module "my_module" {
  # Your module parameters
}

resource "azurerm_container_app" "example" {
  name                         = "example-app"
  container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.example.id
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  revision_mode                = "Single"

  template {
    container {
      name   = "examplecontainerapp"
      image  = "mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/containerapps-helloworld:latest"
      cpu    = 0.25
      memory = "0.5Gi"

        env {
            name = "keyname"
            value = "keyvalue"
        }

        env {
            name = "testname"
            value = module.my_module.my_module_value
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but the need is to update container once its created so in our case. Module1(create "azurerm_container_app"), Module 2(create some resource), Module 3(update container create in module 1) with new environment value which will come from module 2.

Comment: Why do you need to wait until after the container is created? What possible value is there in deploying it without all the environment variables, and then updating it after?

Comment: I really appreciate your willingness to help. There are certain things we are doing which is not very common and can't explain here. :( But the goal is to add new environment variable once the container app is created. One another option that @thoms suggested in the comment is to merge all env variable and then add all again. That looks like the best solution

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in the questions that "How can I update single environment value with the help of "azapi_update_resource" or is it not possible?" if you couldn't understand my question I can't help it.

Answer (score -1):

So I have found one solution, please feel free to comment if there are better options available

Added null resource like below

```
resource "null_resource" "update_env_value" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_container_app.example]
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az containerapp update --name example-app --resource-group resource_groupn --set-env-vars azkey=azvalue3"
  }
}
```